# having condition problem by fetching data in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to fetch data using GET from API and what I want is to use the response in a conditional statement and if the value from the json is null navigate me to login and if it is not null navigate me to the home app...[This is the code I have written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99fXb.png)
the error[the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oaRA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are missing the property Name here:

```
responseJson[0].propertyName != null
```

Comment: propertyName as in

Comment: please upload the responseJson snapshot

Comment: the thing is the Api has the ip address and name of the person who is connected to the wifi ...i am trying to do is validate the is if the person is connected to ip i will automatically fetch from get and see if the value is null or not...json response is "Shruti"

Comment: I assume that jsonResponse is an array. 

I assume it is like this

let j = [{'a': '1', 'b':'2', 'c':'3'}]

console.log(j[0].a) //output 1

Comment: yes right so it shows error ...i am attaching the screenshot